# Domain does not resolve - error message from receiving MTA

Tags: domain-name-system, smtp, centos7

For the first time in my life, I am the owner of an "unsupported" dedicated server, hosted in Europe, I am in Zimbabwe. I transferred various domains from a VPS to this new server, apparently pretty successfully. The server runs headless Centos 7 with Exim and Dovecot handling the mail.

I am having one particular problem. Certain receiving MTA's defer mail from our domains with this error:

```
LOG: MAIN
SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM: SIZE=1803: 
451 4.1.8 Domain of sender address brian@earthstation.mobi does not resolve SMTP>>
QUIT
```

earthstation.mobi does not have a dedicated IP address. I have checked /etc/hosts and /var/cpanel/namedipservers.yaml as well as the DNS zone file for earthstation.mobi and cannot see anything that should be a problem.

```
 dig a earthstation.mobi
 ; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-18.el7_1.3 <<>> a earthstation.mobi
 ;; global options: +cmd
 ;; Got answer:
 ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 16457
 ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 5, ADDITIONAL: 1
 ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
 ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
 ;; QUESTION SECTION:
 ;earthstation.mobi.             IN      A
 ;; ANSWER SECTION:
 earthstation.mobi.      7369    IN      A       5.189.162.242

 ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
 earthstation.mobi.      14400   IN      NS      ns2.bearwebb.com.
 earthstation.mobi.      14400   IN      NS      ns3.contabo.net.
 earthstation.mobi.      14400   IN      NS      ns1.contabo.net.
 earthstation.mobi.      14400   IN      NS      ns1.bearwebb.com.
 earthstation.mobi.      14400   IN      NS      ns2.contabo.net.

 ;; Query time: 2 msec
 ;; SERVER: 213.136.95.11#53(213.136.95.11)
 ;; WHEN: Thu Sep 03 09:32:12 CAT 2015
```

If you can assist with guidance, I will be greatly appreciative.

Many Thanks
Brian

Answer (score 4):

The name servers at `contabo.net` do not answer correctly for your domain:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.2-P3 <<>> soa earthstation.mobi @ns1.contabo.net +norecurse
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 26338
;; flags: qr; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;earthstation.mobi.     IN  SOA

;; Query time: 136 msec
;; SERVER: 79.143.182.242#53(79.143.182.242)
;; WHEN: Thu Sep 03 10:43:53 CEST 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 35
```

So if a certain lookup of your domain will work or not depends entirely on which of the five NS records gets picked. If it's a `bearwebb.com` one, it will work. If it's a `contabo.net` one, it will not.

You should either have the `contabo.net` servers fixed, or remove them as name servers for your domain.

Comment: I have created zone files on my hosts server via their web interface, which has created the correct entries in the n*.contabo.net records. Good advice, well received. Problems resolved. Thank you kindly.